# save the html once we call html through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I want to call one html through ajax. once i get the response,  i need to save that   response as html on the spefied location
how can i do that?

I am calling ajax function using jquery as like below.

```
$.ajax({    
    type: "POST",    
    url: "../../../project/html/TC_print.html",
    success: function(msg){    
        //once it success.. i need to save it as html on desktop
    }  
 });
```

success call back, i need to save it as html on desktop

Answer (score 4):

> //once it success.. i need to save it as html on desktop

Forget about it. For security reasons, javascript that runs inside a browser doesn't have access to files on the client computer. Simply think of the consequences if this was possible. You probably wouldn't have been writing this question nor I have been writing this answer at the very moment as our computers would have been hacked badly. You visit a site and files start popping on your desktop. You visit a malicious site and viruses start popping everywhere, not only on your desktop.

Comment: thank you darin for quick reply. But, as per our requirement, some how we need to save the content on desktop. as Paric suggested, how can we save the file as jsp after ajax call success response?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript prevents you from saving files to a users computer for security reasons, You'd need to write the file to a server and then prompt the user to download the file by putting it in a ZIP or something similar.

Comment: thank you patrick. Can you please elaborate it. as i am using jsp, can we write file at server as a jsp?

Comment: You'll want to use server side code (Java) to create a ZIP file with the contents of what you want to supply to the user. Then link/forward the user to that ZIP which will prompt them to download it. You can't prompt a user to save a JSP file as your server is configured to render this as a page and not allow for download. Check out this Java library. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that with javascript alone you will be able to save on the desktop but I might be mistaken. What I would do will to make another call from the success handler to a php script and pass in the html, then use PHP protocols to save file on desktop. Cheers.